# OutOfMemoryException with MemoryStream()

Tags: c#-3.0, out-of-memory, memorystream

I have a problem of OutOfMemoryException in this piece of C# code.

```
private void SaveZip(IDataReader reader, string header, string fileName, Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(header);
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0)); //exception occurs here
                }

                writer.Close();
            }

            zip.AddEntry(fileName, stream.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

The code tries to write the DataReader object into a file, which being zipped at the end of the procedure. The problem is that the Reader contains a large set of data, about 150MB, and it originates the exception when I try to write the stream on memory.
How could I resolve this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Does this code work as-is for smaller data sets?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have enough memory to process the data to an in-memory buffer, then you'll have to store it out side of memory, like disk.  e.g. replace `MemoryStream` with a `FileStream`

Comment: Ok but it costs a lot of time, isn't it? Is there a way to split data?

Comment: You could use `BufferedStream` to wrap a `FileStream` to have a maximum sized in-memory buffer.